# sw size qualifier

Tags: android, dimensions

I have misunderstanding how sw switch works in android,for example if I am creating values for sw320dp,the system will use this values if the minimum width of the smallest side of the phone is 320dp,but what is the maximum width of the screen in dp it will cover?Will these values be used also for the phones which sw is for example 480dp?

Comment: if smallest width < 480 dp then sw-320dp qualifier will be used other wise 480dp. sw qualifier is independent of screen orientation.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar But what if I only want to change my values small screen sizes and don't want to add sw480dp ,because it's working good

Comment: then use default values for small screen sizes i.e < 320dp and sw-320 for rest of them.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar thanks friend. It helps alot